# Setting cookies not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I wnat to set cookie with a name **csrf_cookie_name** with a value from this function **$this->security->get_csrf_hash();** but, it is not working.

I have this in my controller:

```
   $csrf_cookie_value = $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
   $this->input->set_cookie('csrf_cookie_name', $csrf_cookie_value);
   echo $this->input->cookie('csrf_cookie_name'); 
   die();
```

But it is not working and nothing is echoed out.

If I try only this:

```
 $csrf_cookie_value =  $this->security->get_csrf_hash();
 echo $csrf_cookie_value;
```

I works and a generated string is echoed out.

So, I assume that something within these next 2 lines is wrong:

```
$this->input->set_cookie('csrf_cookie_name', $csrf_cookie_value);
echo $this->input->cookie('csrf_cookie_name');
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: not too sure how it works in PHP, but my guess is that when you try and read the cookie it is reading from the Request Headers and obviously it will not be there since the cookie was not set when the request was made.. check once the response is sent whether the cookie is set in the browser. further requests should read the cookie value correctly.. Note I may be wrong..

Comment: I have set it with $this->input->set_cookie('csrf_cookie_name', $csrf_cookie_value); before I tried to echo it.

Comment: I know you have.. consider reading about Http Request and Response and how cookies work..

Comment: why are you adding the csrf to the cookie? You already have it stored in the security section? You could 'copy' it to the session - but that makes no sense? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I am using it in links not in forms so I need to access it directly.

Comment: When I delete something in user section, the link need to have the csrf hash at the end and it should be different every page reload. Not just for session, which can be several hours etc. I need t to be different every page reload.

Comment: So, you need a unique string hash for each page load, added to the cookie?

Answer (score 20):

You need to specify a life time for the cookie. `0` will be a session cookie and anything else will be added to `time()`.

If you don't specify a life time, CI will interpret that you want to **delete** the cookie. And that's exactly what it does :)

```
$this->input->set_cookie('name', 'value', 0);    //expires when the browser window closes
$this->input->set_cookie('name', 'value', 3600); //expires in one hour
$this->input->set_cookie('name', 'value');       //will delete the cookie (if the cookie does not exist, you will not notice anything happening)
```

Comment: This is correct, you need an expiry date. If you don't set one (or sent a non numeric value) the Input library will set an expiry date in the past (which as far as I can tell is the same as not setting it at all)

Comment: Thanks saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 7):

The reason you are not getting a cookie echoed is because the `$this->input->cookie()` function reads directly from the global `$_COOKIE` array and `$this->input->set_cookie()` does not populate the `$_COOKIE` array immediately on the server. Instead, `$this->input->set_cookie()` queues the cookie to be sent back and stored in the browser. Only on the users' next HTTP request will you be able to re-observe this cookie.

Secondly, and perhaps more importantly, is that I think you are using the csrf cookie improperly. To protect against cross site request forgery only requires you to enable it and set it's properties in `config/config.php`. That is it. There is no need to read and write it in the controllers at all.

Comment: I am using it in links not in forms so I need to access it directly.

Answer (score 3):

The cookie is already there. You can consult via Javascript with:

```
$.cookie("<?php echo $this->config->item("csrf_cookie_name"); ?>");
```

I hope be useful.