# Codeigniter HMVC and cookies

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I'm trying to figure out why cookies don't work in my environment.

This is my controller and it is placed in modules/cookie/controller/cookie.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class cookie extends MX_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function set_cookie()
        {
            $this->input->set_cookie('test_cookie', 'My cookie value'); 
        }

        public function get_cookie()
        {
            var_dump($this->input->cookie('test_cookie',TRUE));
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I've found the solution at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/12527792/1820242

Comment: Why are not working? What is the code you use for setting and retrieving them?

Comment: Well, just a simple question back: Why do you expect that code to work?

Comment: That is the code.

www.mywebsite.com/cookie/set_cookie should save the test cookie and then .../get_cookie should show my cookie but always prints FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are loading the `cookie` helper, maybe you have configured secure cookies while browsing non-secure urls. Try to set the cookie with an array property to see if it is set correctly, disabling the secure cookie creation:

```
$cookie = array(
 'name'   => 'test_cookie',
 'value'  => 'Cookie value',
 'expire' => '3600',
 'domain' => '.your.domain',
 'path'   => '/',
 'prefix' => 'yourprefix_',
 'secure' => FALSE
);

$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

Comment: Assuming that the cookie helper is just an alias for $this->input->set_cookie($cookie) is not mandatory to load it.

The secure parameter is default FALSE and I'm in localhost so my domain must be '/'

I also tried with your array and with the array that is in the documentation but still doesn't works.